# grep or pcregrep for multi line wrapped text patterns

Tags: regex, grep

I need a solution for pattern matching in a file with line continuation characters (like '\'). I have a file with commands (my first partial pattern) then any number of line wraps (zero to N) and then a second partial pattern that I search for.

Let's say I look for any command line that has the cmd 'mycmd' and the argument 'myarg'on the same line or after any number of line wraps '\'.

File :

```
xcmd xarg
xcmd \
 xarg
xcmd xarg yarg \
 myarg \
 zarg
mycmd myarg
mycmd \
 xarg
mycmd yarg
mycmd \
 myarg
mycmd zarg \
 myarg xarg \
 yarg
```

Out of that my biological grep would expect:

```
mycmd myarg
mycmd \
 myarg
mycmd zarg \
 myarg xarg \
 yarg
```

I'm OK if the '\' are omitted in the prinout.

My thinking is to have a regexp that searches for 'mycmd' followed by 0 to N '\ + CR' followed by 'myarg'.

Thank you for helping.
Gert

Comment: Did you try what you are thinking? How well did it work? What went wrong?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v cmd="mycmd" -v arg="myarg" '
       $0 ~ cmd && $0 ~ arg {s=1; line=$0; next}
       s && /\\ *$/{line = line RS $0; next}
       s && !/\\ *$/{s=0; print line RS $0}' file
```